# In VSTS how to enable rollup for completed work and original estimate for all tasks under User Story

Tags: azure-devops

I noticed that by default VSTS adds up remaining work, but does not sum up neither completed work nor original estimate.

What needs to be done to set this up?

I do have some admin access to VSTS, but not sure this will be sufficient...

[image]

I even found this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields?view=vsts

but I still can't figure out how to enable it in VSTS

Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say you can't "enable it". The link you provided gives many different options to obtain the information you're after. Which one were you attempting to implement?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t such feature in VSTS now, (VSTS (Hosted XML) is supported: [Rollup estimated and actual work using Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/office/rollup-estimated-and-actual-work-using-project?view=vsts)).

There is a UserVoice: [Rollup Completed Work](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32129575-rollup-completed-work).

You can to do it through this extension: [VSTS RollUp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=canarysautomationspvtltd.vstsrollup), which is based on the web hook to update work item, the result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Canarys Rollup can help you with Rollup of Effort fields.
You can optionally choose for Remaining work auto calculation as well.

Please try out [Canarys Rollup](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=canarysautomationspvtltd.canarysrollup)

[image]